# UILabel set text unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, optional-values

In my custom collectionview cell I have

```
@IBOutlet weak var boardNameLabel: UILabel!

var boardInfoDic: Dictionary? = [String : AnyObject]() 

func updateItemAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let string = boardInfoDic?["description"]
        {
            boardNameLabel.text = String(format: "%@", string as! String)
        }
}
```

and i am sending data to boardInfoDic from `collectionView` `cellForItemAt indexPath:` as

```
let boardsCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: KBoardsCollectionViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BoardsCollectionViewCell
boardsCollectionViewCell.boardInfoDic = self.boardsDataArray?[indexPath.item] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?
boardsCollectionViewCell.updateItemAtIndexPath(indexPath as NSIndexPath)
```

but I am getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, I was tried in multiple ways but no use. How can I fix this issue?

Outlet connection with UICollectionViewCell 
[image]

Comment: Change line to `if let string = boardInfoDic?["description"] as? String` and then simply boardNameLabel.text = string.

Comment: @NiravD I got same error after changing the code also

Comment: @NiravD updated the question with reference to outlet, I am getting mad from last night to fix the issue.

Comment: Can you say where it is exactly your app crashing.

Answer (score 0):

First confirm your boardInfoDic is not empty.  Use this

```
    func updateItemAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

                print(boardInfoDic)
                boardNameLabel.text = String(self.boardInfoDic["description"]!)   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do `if let string = boardInfoDic?["description"]`  that variable `string` is not of type `String` it is of type `AnyObject`.  As a result, when you cast `string` to be a `String`, it is unable to make this type type cast, and, as a result, returns nil.  in order to get a string from your dictionary, you need to access it with something of type `AnyObject`.  For example

```
if let string = boardInfoDic?["description"]
        {
            boardNameLabel.text = String(format: "%@", string as! String)
        }
```

Be sure to mark this as the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try optional conversion

```
if let string = boardInfoDic?["description"] as? String {
    boardNameLabel.text = String(format: "%@", string)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
if let string = boardInfoDic?["description"] as? String
    {
        boardNameLabel?.text = string
    }
```